# JIRA error while trying demo in custom message handler tutorial

Tags: maven, jira, message-handlers

I was doing the tutorial for creating custom message handler.
The [tutorial link](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/guides/email/tutorial-custom-message-mail-handler-for-JIRA)

I followed exactly the same then when I attempt to run "atlas-run" command, a Build Failure message always appear with this error code

> Failed to execute goal on project mail-handler-demo: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project
>   com.example.plugins.tutorial.jira:mail-handler-demo:atlassian-plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failure to find com.atlassian.jira:jira-mail-plugin:jar:7.0.0-1 in
>   https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of atlassian-public has elapsed or updates are forced ->
>   [Help 1]

Is the "com.atlassian.jira:jira-mail-plugin:jar:7.0.0-1" file being changed or updated? Or is there any other reason that causing this error? 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason. It was due to outdated version information given in the tutorial link. It has been updated now upon request